# creating deep object property with string

Tags: javascript

How do you create a deep nested property using a string?
I know you can use bracket notation, but if you're trying to create a nested property. i.e.

```
Obj{
   l1:{
      l2:{}
   }
}
```

It doesn't work as I want it to. I get an obj property of "levelTwo.two" as opposed to an actual property of "levelTwo",followed by another nested property of "two".    See example below:

```js
var obj = {};
var value= 'test';
var str = "levelOne";
var str2 ="levelTwo.two";
var strX = "levelX";

obj[str] = value
console.log(obj);

obj[str2]= value;
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: You never defined `obj`.

Comment: @Mathletics copy/paste error.  Updated

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24221803/javascript-access-object-multi-level-property-using-variable/24221895#24221895

Comment: Per comments, this is a duplicate. Also want to mention that I found the 'lodash' lib has a "set" method to support this operation.